# Vertical line in matrix in gauss package

Tags: environments, matrices

I am currently using the `gauss` package since I need to write out operations between my matrices. However I am unable to add a vertical line to the far right in my augmented matrices. The `gauss` package is unable to act upon array-environments, but rather it uses its own `gmatrix`-environment. I found this workaround: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/ but its not applicable to `gmatrix`-environments. Any ideas, forum?

Comment: Help much appreciated forum!

Comment: Can you add a MWE starting from `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}` with necessary preamble?. This will increase your chances of getting an answer.